# Why does closing a form and then going to a variable cause my powershell to crash?

Tags: winforms, powershell, button

So I have a script where I am trying to make a GUI version of a text menu. I currently have an option from the text menu to launch a GUI menu. I want a button to return to the text menu but make the close button (the "x") on the form exit the script entirely.

I thought I can just close the GUI with `Form.Close()` and then call my text menu variable afterwards but that causes my PowerShell session to crash.

Here is the code I mentioned nested within an `Add_Click` scriptblock:

```
$Text_Menu.Add_Click({
    $MainMenu_GUI.Close()
        .$MainMenu
    })
```

I was hoping this would close the GUI and just return to the text menu but it instead has a way more catastrophic result...Anyone know why, or maybe how I can accomplish what I described the desired result to be? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You need a space between the `.` and the `$MainMenu` to call a script that might be stored in `$MainMenu`    > `. $MainMenu`

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Close probably has a special meaning and is normally called by the [Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) method. Hide or Hidden might be what you are after but I need an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be sure.

```
try {
    $Text_Menu = # MISSING CODE THAT CREATES SOME OBJECT
    # Source example https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-interactive-menu/
    $Text_Menu.Add_Click({ return }) 
} finally { 
    $MainMenu_GUI.Dispose()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set to DialogResult.Cancel. Unlike non-modal forms, the Close method is not called by the .NET Framework when the user clicks the close form button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

from [Form.ShowDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8)

> The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

from [Form.Close Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netframework-4.8)

> Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used, or the form is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your application.

from [Form.Dispose(Boolean) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dispose?view=netframework-4.8)

However:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,150) 

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,50)
$Button.Text = "Close"
$Button.add_click({$form.close()})

$form.Controls.Add($Button)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Works just fine for me...
The Problem must be in `$MainMenu`